# Xpath explanation

Tags: excel, xml, xpath, excel-formula

Hello i want to ask what exactly this Xpath does if we use.

I understand that it selects all b nodes that appear before the current node and that are not the same with current node.

```
//b[not(preceding::*=.)]
```

So if xml is like:

```
<a>
 <b>English</b>
 <b>German</b>
 <b>Italian</b>
 <b>Belarusian</b>
 <b>Russian</b>
 <b>Bulgarian</b>
 <b>French</b>
 <b>English</b>
</a>
```

Does this keep the last occurrence of the node or the first? this is what i do not get.

I was thinking that it should keep the last but using this xpath in FILTERXML function i gives the result of keeping the first occurrence so the result was

{"English";"German";"Italian";"Belarusian";"Russian";"Bulgarian";"French"}

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
//b[not(preceding::*=.)]
```

selects all `b` elements that do not have a preceding element with the same [***string value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value).

One might use this XPath to select only the first such elements, eliminating later "duplicates."

**Notes:**

1. To limit the scope to preceding `b` elements, use `//b[not(preceding::b=.)]`.
2. To limit the scope to preceding `b` *sibling* elements, use `//b[not(preceding-sibling::b=.)]`

Answer (score 0):

It means "select all `b` nodes for which there doesn't exist a preceding node equal to the reference node". Therefore, keeping the first and rejecting the last is the correct behaviour.